# Inequality between norms in $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces for $p,q>1$

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

If I define $2$ continuous probability density functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ for which $L^p$ and $L^q$ norms are defined for $p>1$ and $q>1$,

Is it correct to say that

$\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{p}>\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{p}\quad\quad\Rightarrow\quad\quad\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{q}>\left\Vert g\right\Vert _{q}\qquad?$

In the discrete world, that is, in $l^p$ and $l^q$, a similar claim would mean that two (probability) vectors can be compared with any norm; if a vector is "greater" than another vector based on a p-norm measurement, then it would also be greater than this other vector based on a q-norm measurement.

I have searched through various theoretical work but couldn't find an answer, in particular in the continuous world (which is the one I am interested in). In the discrete world ($l^p$ and $l^q$), I came across the notion of "Unit balls" and the claim might be true and related to the fact that the Unit balls for various p or q do not cross each other (as you can read, I am not an expert in this).

I have also tried to show it numerically for discrete $l^p$ and $l^q$ norms (so applied to discrete probability distributions) and my results tend to confirm the claim in the discrete case.  I cannot find any answer in the continuous case though.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Both? There's only one claim being made...

Comment: For every $p,q$, no relation between them?

Comment: Yes, for any p,q both larger than 1 (in my application, they are not Holder-conjugates of each other). I am mostly interested in p and q both comprised between 1 and 2 but I have written my question "in general" because in the discrete case that I have investigated, it seems to me that the claim is true for any value of p and q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of $\ell^p$ spaces on 2 points, its impossible because the entire space of random variables is parameterised by a single number $a\in[0,1]$,
$$ X_a=a\delta_0 + (1-a)\delta_1 $$
which has $p$ norm given by (for $p\ge 1$)
$$N_a(p) := \|X_a\|_{\ell^p}^p = a^p + (1-a)^p$$
and the graphs of $N_a,N_b$ only intersect at $p=1$, unless $a=b$.
Forgetting about the continuity requirement for now, this corresponds to the piecewise constant random variables defined e.g. explicitly on $\Omega = [0,1]$,
$$ x_a =2a\mathbb1_{[0,1/2] } + 2(1-a)\mathbb 1_{[1/2,1]}$$
in the sense that
$$ \|x_a\|_{L^p[0,1]}^p=N_a(p)$$
But on $[0,1]$, we can (among other things) also choose to shrink/expand the intervals $[0,1/2],[1/2,1]$; we have a whole new dimension of parameters,
$$ x_{a,c} := \frac{a}{c}\mathbb1_{[0,c] } + \frac{1-a}{1-c}\mathbb 1_{[c,1]}, \quad a,c\in(0,1)$$
and their norms are given by
$$N_{a, c}(p) = c\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^p+(1-c)\left(\frac{1-a}{1-c}\right)^p$$
and it is possible to find parameter pairs $(a,c),(b,d)$ and exponents $p,q\in(1,2)$ such that
$$N_{a, c}(p) < N_{b,d}(p),\quad N_{a, c}(q) > N_{b,d}(q)$$
Here is an [interactive](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mcwjddjqcq) graph; the shaded areas for $x\in[0,1]$ are the probability distributions and the graphs for $x>1$ are the $L^x$ norms. The orange line is a plot of $\operatorname{sign}(N_{a, c}(x) - N_{b, d}(x))$, showing the sign flip in the region $(1,2)$.
[image]

(the graph is more believable for larger values of $p,q$)

If you must insist on continuous functions, you can use approximating sequences of continuous functions that converge in some $L^P$ norm for some large (finite) $P> p+q$,
$$ x_{a,c,n} \to x_{a, c} , \quad x_{b, d,n} \to x_{b, d} \quad (n\to\infty)$$

Then since by Holder's, if $P_0<P$ then $$\|u\|_{L^{P_0}} \le \|u\|_{L^P}$$
the above convergences hold in $L^p$ and $L^q$ as well, and they converge at least as quickly as they do in $L^P$. This implies that we can simultaneously control the errors in their norms
$$ |\|x_{a,c,n}\|_{L^p} - N(a, c)(p)^{1/p}| <\epsilon $$
$$ |\|x_{a,c,n}\|_{L^q} - N(a, c)(q)^{1/q}| <\epsilon $$
$$|\|x_{b,d,n}\|_{L^p} - N(b, d)(p)^{1/p}| <\epsilon $$
$$ |\|x_{b,d,n}\|_{L^q} - N(b, d)(q)^{1/q}| <\epsilon $$ 
and therefore for $n\gg1$, we again get a sign flip as we vary the exponent.

It should also be false for the discrete case because this should correspond to at worst, a very finely discretised grid.

---

And after all that, [here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yvuoncak3s) a counterexample for the case of random variables that uniformly randomly take 3 values (i.e. $\ell^p$ on 3 points)

[image]

Comment: NB The result is very easily false for functions, if you don't enforce integral 1. You can just consider
$$ f_{\epsilon,N}(x) = \min(N, \epsilon |x|^{-(1/p)})$$
for $\epsilon\ll 1$, the $L^{q_0}$ norm for $q_0<p$ can be made as small as you like, for arbitrary $N$. But for $q_1 > p$, the norm is unbounded as $N\to\infty$. I don't know if the result for pdfs should have been just as easy to prove...

Comment: Your diagrams are extremely helpful. I have noticed that both in the 2 point cases and in the 3 point cases, the diagrams of the norms cross each other in p=q=1 (because that was the initial requirement) and then - sometimes, depending on the distribution parameters - in a second point. But they never cross in three points. Do you think that this is by accident or would there be a mathematical explanation that would make that feature general and valid even beyond 3 points?

Comment: @Lucky Glad they help. I think its both "by accident" and also provable, but I definitely didn't bother to prove it since I was happy to just find a counterexample. I believe a counterexample on 3 points is a counterexample in $n>3$ points because you can just take those values $4,5,\dots,n$ with probability 0. I can't remember the problem vividly anymore but I suppose this would work also if they they took the values $4,5,\dots,n$ with a very small probability

Comment: I realized I misphrased my question; I should have written: I have noticed that both in the 2 point cases and in the 3 point cases, the diagrams of the norms cross each other one time in p=q=1 (because that was the initial requirement) and then - sometimes, depending on the distribution parameters - they cross twice. But they never cross three times or more. Do you think that the fact that the norm diagrams cross max two times is an accident or would there be a mathematical explanation that would make that feature general and valid even beyond 3 points (for a completely general distribution)?

Comment: @Lucky only after you pointed out the ambiguity do I see it :) I believe my answer remains the same